# Return last value in a row - do not consider formula as value - Excel 2016

Tags: excel-formula

I want to find the last value of a row in a given range. Each cell in this row is populated via a formula. So, if hte formula succeeds, it has a value, otherwise it shows null.
This is the formula for every cell in the row
`=SUM(J$36:J$45)`

To find the last value in the row, at the end cell of the row, i have this formula `=LOOKUP(2,1/(J47:T47<>""),J47:T47)` for the range J47:T47. 
This forumula works when every cell has a text or number. In my case, since every cell already had the formula, it considers formula also as not null and gives alway the value of the last cell(which in my case was null since sum was 0/null). What i want is to consider only the cells that really has a value - meaning the sum would have given some number. How do i tweak the formula to say `value is not null or not formula`

Comment: A solution will depend on what version you have.

Comment: This is excel 2016